# iOS - new line character in UITextView

Tags: ios, uitextview, newline

Reading in text from a data file. How can I get line breaks to work? I've tried \n, but it just puts "\n" into the string instead of creating a new line.

EDIT:
The text is coming from a web service, which does not have true line breaks in the text.

Comment: Please, post a sample of this in code.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1975494/adding-a-newline-to-a-uitextview

Comment: And if you are in Interface Builder: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/860940/how-to-get-uitextview-to-respect-newlines-in-interface-builder

Comment: does your data include HTML tags ?

Comment: No HTML tags. I just want to create a new line in the UITextView if I encounter a new line character in the text. Such as "this is my \n test text".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not understand your problem, doing it this way I get this result:

script to create the test file:

```
#!/bin/sh
(cat <<- EOF
i am
a
test file
EOF
) > /tmp/test.txt
```

objective c code:

```
NSString *str = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:@"/tmp/test.txt" encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:nil];
NSLog(@"%@", str);
```

my output:

```
i am
a
test file
```

I hope you can be useful.

Comment: that would work in a basic text file, but the text is coming from a web service. I have edited my question to reflect this.

Comment: Going to accept this answer. The web service has a limitation of not allowing line breaks, so in this case there is no solution.